# MySQL: IN vs EXISTS with values (no subquery)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm aware that when using a subquery, `IN` will use a count of the rows, and `EXISTS` will return a boolean as soon as a match is found in the results.

I've also read that `IN` beats `EXISTS` when the number of results of the subquery are low, and `EXISTS` will beat `IN` when there are many results.

I want to know if I specify values in the SQL query how does `IN` perform vs `EXISTS` for example:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM table
WHERE col1 IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);

SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM table
WHERE col1 EXISTS (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
```

What happens when the list of values is "large" as in a few hundred/thousand values?

Comment: Have you ever heard of the phrase "micro optimization is the root of all evil"? I think it applies here. When in doubt, run the queries yourself, and check the performance.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this myself, but wanted to understand what it's going to do first. Who said this was a "micro optimization" though?

Comment: Before posting the question did you try any of these queries even if they are valid?

Comment: `IN` loads all available values and tries to match them, while `EXISTS` is a boolean operator. So depending on your result set, `IN` is probably faster for small result sets while `EXISTS` can be an advantage with larger ones.

Comment: Have you compared their explain plans?

Comment: to add to @Paul 's comment `col1 IN (1, 2[, ...])` is syntax sugar for `col1 = 1 OR col = 2 [,..]` which believe it or not optimizes badly in MySQL..Topicstarter you can better run `SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM table
WHERE col1 = 1 UNION SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM table
WHERE col1 = 2` (will be long with  hundred/thousand) or with a delivered table approach   ... `SELECT * FROM(SELECT 1 AS search_id UNION SELECT 2 AS search_id [,...]) AS search INNER JOIN your_table.col1 = search,seach_id` (will be long with hundred/thousand)

Comment: ... MySQL should ideally optimize the OR optimisation maybe it happen with fully supported Parallel Query execution.. Which seams on it way [MySQL 8.0.14: A Road to Parallel Query Execution is Wide Open!](https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/01/23/mysql-8-0-14-a-road-to-parallel-query-execution-is-wide-open/)

Comment: *"Have you ever heard of the phrase "micro optimization is the root of all evil"?"* @FrankerZ no i haven't but i but i believe you meant *"Premature Optimization Is the Root of All Evil"*

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the queries?  This is not syntactically valid:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM t
WHERE col1 EXISTS (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ab9952f5b63371483de6857a27933a14) is a db<>fiddle.

If you have a fixed list of values, then basically your only choice is to use `IN` (or `OR` or a subquery).  MySQL optimizes `IN` by sorting a list of constant values.